# Linux image with MySQL installed

Tags: mysql, linux

Is there somewhere you can get an ISO image for linux - preferably CentOS or Ubuntu - with MySQL pre-installed and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian has pre-installed mysql If you select option while install.
http://www.debian.org/CD/

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS, you could install MySQL with:

yum install community-mysql community-mysql-server

On Ubuntu, with:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```